# request parameter cannot be gotten

Tags: python, django

Request parameter cannot be obtained. I want to search whether "file" is in request parameter or not. I written the following code:

```
def common_logic(request):
    data = request.POST.get('data', None)

    if 'file' in request.POST:
        file = request.FILES['file'].temporary_file_path()
    else:
        file = None
    return file
```

However, when I set file parameter, always else statement is read. When I print out `print(request.POST)`, `<QueryDict: {'data': ['100']}>` is shown so file parameter cannot be obtained. I want to get file parameter and search whether `request.POST` has file or not. Why can't I get file parameter? How can I get this?

Comment: `fil=request.FILES.get('file');file = fil.temporary_file_path() if fil else None` , You don't need to check for file attribute in `request.POST`

Comment: Try `if request.FILES:` instead of `if 'file' in request.POST:`. Not able to test atm but `.POST` and `.FILES` are different attributes.

Comment: @roganjosh thx ur comments.I wrote ur code,but AttributeError at /app/common_logic
'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'temporary_file_path' error happens.How should I fix this?

Comment: @AvinashRaj thx ur comments.I wrote ur code like     `fil = request.FILES.get('file')
    if fil:
        file = fil.temporary_file_path() else None`but always program is in else statement.How should I fix this?

Comment: @user8817477 check whether the request contain multipart-form-data

Comment: @AvinashRaj how can I check it?

Comment: how you make the request? via postman?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes,it is via POSTMAN

Comment: use form-data, set param 'file' and value "image file" and don't set the headers. Now try again.